# Reading MaxPoolSize via MBean in EAP 7.1

Tags: jboss-eap-7

how can I get the maxPoolSize of a datasource via mbean?

In JBoss 6 it was jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,xa-data-source=MyDataSource -> maxPoolSize

In EAP 7.1 it doesn't exist anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,this does not exist in `EAP 7.1` anymore,

`mbeans`
 have been replaced by the `native management API`.

To know the max-pool-size of a datasource you could try the below given command from CLI instead after starting the server:
This would give you a complete insight into datasource parameters values.

`./jboss-cli.sh --connect
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS/statistics=pool:read-resource(include-runtime=true`